# Advice on SQL Server database architecture

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2014

We have a medium-sized web application (multiple instances), querying against a single SQL Server 2014 database.

Not the must robust architecture, no clustering/failover, and we have been getting a few deadlocks recently.

I'm looking at how i can improve the performance and availability of the database, reduce these deadlocks, and have a better backup/failover strategy.

I'm not a DBA, so looking for some advice here.

We currently have the following application architecture:

- Multiple web servers reading and writing to a single SQL Server DB
- Multiple background services reading and writing to the same single SQL Server DB

I'm contemplating making the following changes:

- Split the single DB into two DB's, one *read-only* and another *read-write*. The *read-write* DB replicates the data to the *read-only* DB using SQL Server replication
- Web servers connect to the given DB depending on the operation.
- Background servers connect to the *read-write* DB (most the writes happen here)

Most of the DB queries on the web servers are reads (and a lot of the writes can be offloaded to the background services), so that's the reason for my thoughts here.

I could then also potentially add clustering to the *read-only* databases.

Is this a good SQL Server database architecture? Or would the DBA's out there simply suggest a clustering approach?

Goals: performance, scalability, reliability

Comment: voting to move this to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific details about your server, it's tough to give you specific advice (for example, what's a medium-sized web application? what are the specs on your database server? What's your I/O latency like?  CPU contention?  Memory utilization?)

At a high level of abstraction, deadlocks usually occur because of two reasons:

1. Your reads are too slow, and
2. Your writes are too slow.

There's lots of ways to address both of those issues, but in general:

1. You can cover a lot of coding sins with good hardware, and
2. Don't re-architect a solution until you've pursued performance tuning options (including indexing strategies and/or procedure rewrites).

Clustering is generally considered to be used as a strategy for High Availability/Disaster Recovery, not performance augmentation (there are always exceptions).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I get what you are saying, but i'm also seeking advice on a high level, not specific ways to address problems. I'm just concerned about having multiple components all reading and writing to the same single database, and was thinking it needs to be split out.

Comment: That can be an expensive solution for a problem that usually has a cheap fix :)  A well tuned database server can handle a LOT of load before resorting to a replica.